# Execute query count in Realm Studio

Tags: realm

How can i exceute a query count on Realm Studio?

I have to get the number of rows for a specific user, in the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/) i can't find it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to do this in code. Realm Studio queries can only filter what objects you're seeing, in my experience.